# Kentico 9 smart search partial word results

Tags: kentico

I was asked to look into this, but i don't think it works they way people think it should. My site is here: https://www.knowledgefirstfinancial.ca/

if i search for banking, i get the expecting results: https://www.knowledgefirstfinancial.ca/search-results.aspx?searchtext=banking&searchmode=exactphrase. But searching for Bank doesn't. There is one hit that shows in both, but that result has Bank and Banking.

Can the smart search handle partial words? Flex from Flexibility?

By default i have the search set to 'exactphrase', which i like as a default, but the drop down options don't solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. [Setting up substring search and word stemming](https://docs.kentico.com/k8/configuring-kentico/setting-up-search-on-your-website/configuring-search-assistance-features#Configuringsearchassistancefeatures-Settingupsubstringsearchandwordstemming)

Comment: Thanks, would you have a separate search index for this?

Comment: I guess it depends on your set set up, but normally not. Lets say you have such index defined for some product types in your store and you want these types to be searched this way only.

Comment: Thanks, the site isn't that complex. I've got three here, and I have implemented this on one. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

One more approach to resolve this is to tackle in these two ways.

1. Use Fuzzy search - You will use fuzzy search with a deliberate fuzzy factor say 0.8. This will allow you to have 20% error rates on your search string. However this doesn't guarantee anything and will depend upon text length.
2. A much better approach would be to index your content using a STEM ANALYZER. This analyzer will index stem of a word like fooding->food, walking->walk and so on and so forth. You will select this analyzer while index creation in Kentico and you should be all set.